# Extract pdf_tex graphics from pdf-file

Tags: pdf, latex, extract, inkscape, pdftex

I created a lot of vector graphics with inkscape, where I add a lot of math-code directly in the image (see example below). I normally extract a pdf_tex out of the svg document, and include the pdf_tex in my LaTeX code. After compiling the file in my TEX-editor, a perfect vector graphic occurs.

My question:

- As I would like to make a presentation which uses some images out of my LaTeX-file, is there any chance to extract the compiled pdf_tex images from the compiled pdf-file or maybe directly out of inkscape?

[image: Example of a vector graphic with LaTeX-code inside]

Comment: You could use the [beamer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beamer_(LaTeX)) class, to create your presentation with LaTeX, which could allow you to keep your workflow

Comment: Maybe one of these two questions on tex.stackexchange.com could also help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140796/generating-a-separate-pdf-file-of-tables-and-figures-from-a-latex-file https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134733/splitting-figures-tables-into-separate-files

Comment: @Dugnom: I know this approach, but I need to use powerpoint as a tool. As I understand the approaches in the links, there the images are extracted as pdf. I would like to get a jpg or png (or any other powerpoint capable file extension) out of my pdf_tex files.

Comment: What about importing the graphics as pdfs into ppt? [see this microsoft documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-pdf-file-content-into-a-powerpoint-presentation-5e7719d5-508c-4c07-a3d4-68123c373a62). You could create individual pdfs of your images and import them

Comment: and last possible idea, make indiviual pdfs and convert them to images, see the second part of the accepted answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/compile-a-latex-document-into-a-png-image-thats-as-short-as-possible

Comment: I hate to spam you with comments, but I'm still hoping to help you. This will be my last one, whcih basically is the same idea as the one before: https://latexdraw.com/how-to-convert-a-latex-pdf-to-png/ 
I will try to compile a real answer from this information tomorrow

Comment: Dear both,
I am not sure, whether the approaches work for having pdf_tex images. The pdf_tex exists out of a pdf, which contains the image (no problem to extract a png out of that at all) and a pdf_tex, which contains the text information.
What I did now: I used a  screen with 4K-resolution and I made simple screenshots there. This leads to quite okay result.